# when formating numbers in php i can't see the currency

Tags: php, echo

When I use the function to format the number in PHP I can't see the euro currency even if it exist in the echo, this is my code:

```
<?php  echo number_format(_getSnippet("field_prix" , "vehicule") .'€' , 0, ',', ' '); ?>
```

I need to echo the number like `20 000 €<br>` but I get `20 000<br>`
and when I do:

```
<?php echo  _getSnippet("field_prix" , "vehicule") ." €"; ?>
```

It work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A currency symbol is not a number so you can't format it.  Add it after formatting:

```
<?php echo number_format(_getSnippet("field_prix" , "vehicule"), 0, ',', ' ') .'€'; ?>
```

You're using an outdated version of PHP if you don't getting one of the following with the way you're doing it:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: number_format(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type float, string given